# Video converter using movie.py project advice

Tags: python-3.x, converters, file-conversion

Hello I am working on making a youtube video downloader, and a video converter to practice python language. With the video converter, I am trying to convert an mp4 file to a mp3 file. I want the user to input the specified path without having to open the text editor to do so. My issue is this. I am having trouble trying to figure out how I can possibly, if it is possible, to convert the file using the user's input. Can someone help me with this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
import moviepy.editor as mp 

#ask the user for the location of the file
loca = (input("Please input the location of the video file you wish to convert: "))

# Insert Local Video File Path  
clip = mp.VideoFileClip(r'loca') 
  
# Insert Local Audio File Path 
clip.audio.write_audiofile(r'loca')
```

Answer (score 0):

Just type extension to the file
If you can't imagine here's what's look like.

```py
import moviepy.editor as mp 

#ask the user for the location of the file
loca = (input("Please input the location of the video file you wish to convert: "))
filename = input("File name. : ")
# Insert Local Video File Path  
clip = mp.VideoFileClip(loca) 
  
# Insert Local Audio File Path 
clip.audio.write_audiofile(filename)
```